# VueJS weird $emit behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am experimenting a really weird behaviour from my Vue app.

I have the following two components inside one of my router views:

```js
<bootstrap-table @showcurrent-click="handleShowcurrent"
                 @edit-click="handleEdit" 
                 @delete-click="handleDelete"
                 @generated-id="retrieveID"
                 :columns="columns" 
                 :data="data" 
                 :options="options"></bootstrap-table>

<device-showcurrent :device="showCurrent" 
                    :show="showShowCurrentModal"
                    @modal-close="handleHideShowcurrentModal"></device-showcurrent>
```

#### The problem

Inside my `device-showcurrent` component, which is a Bootstrap modal, I handle the `hide.bs.modal` event with JQuery and emit a custom `modal-close` event so I can handle the event from the router view component (you can see in the previous piece of code the `@modal-close="handleHideShowcurrentModal"`) like this:

```js
mounted: function(){
        // Due to Javascript scope we assign this to a variable
        instance = this
        // This ID is generated on creation, and it works corretly.
        // I also checked that this JQuery event was triggering.
        $(`#${this.randomID}`).on('hide.bs.modal', e => {
            instance.$emit('modal-close')
        })
    }
```

**But the problem is that the event is not emitting from `device-modal`, but from `bootstrap-table`** (checked through VueDevTools), so the first piece of code I posted does not work, but the following does:

```js
<bootstrap-table @showcurrent-click="handleShowcurrent"
                         @edit-click="handleEdit" 
                         @delete-click="handleDelete"
                         @generated-id="retrieveID"
                         @modal-close="handleHideShowcurrentModal"
                         :title="$t('message.audited_devices')" 
                         :columns="columns" 
                         :data="data" 
                         :options="options"></bootstrap-table>

        <device-showcurrent :device="showCurrent" 
                            :show="showShowCurrentModal"></device-showcurrent>
```

#### The question

What is happening here? How is it possible that the custom event is being emitted from another component?

Thank you very much!

Comment: it's a little hard to tell without being able to actually analyze it completly. First thing I'd check: is the `instance` value referencing the table? Instead of using `mounted: function() { ... }` you could try `mounted() { ... }` maybe the function syntax messes up your context.

Comment: Hi @Frnak, thanks for commenting! I actually found the solution, I posted it bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I changed the `mounted` hook to:

```js
mounted: function() {
        let _this = this;
        $(`#${this.randomID}`).on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
            _this.$emit('modal-close')
        })
    }
```

It was probably a scope problem. which has been solved by:

1. Declaring the "instance copy" (`_this`) with `let`.
2. Changing the callback function from the JQuery listener declaration from arrow function to a normal function.

It still feels quite strange because the event was being emitted, but that was probably because I also had an `instance = this` on my `bootstrap-table` component which was being globally scoped (Ì was not using `let` either).